# Unsupported Configuration Multiple Objects Using Identifier "" (Identifiers must be unique)

Tags: xcode4, nstableview, nib

I have just started using array controllers so my experience with them is very limited.

I am getting this warning in XCode 4.1:

> Unsupported Configuration   Multiple Objects Using Identifier ""
>   (Identifiers must be unique)

The double quotes are there with nothing inside. I am using an array controller. It appears for every column of my Table View.  I have checked the bindings on each column.  Each column is bound to a unique identifier [i.e. arrangedObjects.fullName].

Everything seems to work fine and I am thinking I can just ignore it.

Comment: Same here with Xcode 8.3.3. So stupid error. How to fix it..?